# How to send response to fetch API

Tags: post, go, http-post

I am using `fetch` API to send data to my `POST` request...

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/validation', {
    method:'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email:this.state.email,
        password:this.state.password
    })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log("response");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Simple enough, just sending `email` and `password` to `POST` handler. It is received and saved without error, but now I want to send back a custom response.

At the moment, my response throws an error. My `Post` handler looks as follows...

```
func Validate(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)

    var creds credentials

    err := decoder.Decode(&creds)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ...
```

I do not know how to send a response. I'm assuming I need to encode to `json` first and then send it. But how exactly do I send it?

Let's say I want to return a string `"success"`, do I need to `return` it? Or use `fmt.Println()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write your response to to the `http.ResponseWriter`. For example:

```
func Validate(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)

    var creds credentials

    err := decoder.Decode(&creds)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // rw is the HTTP response writer.
    fmt.Fprintf(rw, "success")
}
```

Comment: This will not work because I am encoding it into JSON format. Fprintf does not accept JSON formats

Comment: The proper way to do it was encode it into JSON, then use `rw.Write`

Comment: @Bolboa, marshalled JSON is a byte array, which should work with Fprintf.